# datetime.datetime нет атрибута: "AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'"

Tags: python

Пытался освоить модуль datetime в питоне. Использовал следующий материал
*https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-datetime.html*

Класс `datetime.datetime` - используется очень широко, равно как и в других учебных пособиях. Но при попытке использовать её у себя редактор выдаёт ошибку:

> ```
> AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
> ```

Питон использовался версий 3.2, 3.4
Редактор Py Script 3.2, 3.4 х 64

Это баг, или я чего-то не знаю? Как это побороть?

Comment: Не путайте модуль datetime и класс datetime. Если вы написали `from datetime import datetime`, то тутошний datetime это уже класс, и никакого `datetime.datetime` писать не нужно

Answer (score 1):

Смотри.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 28, 22, 2, 27, 597483)
>>> 
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 28, 22, 2, 37, 813366)
```

Понимаешь в чем разница. Дело в том, как именно ты импортируешь datetime.
Если ты импортируешь пакет, то надо обращаться `имя_пакета.модуль.функция`
Но если ты импортируешь модуль из пакета, то тогда просто `модуль.функция`

Comment: `datetime.datetime` не модуль. Это класс

Comment: Ок. пусть будет класс. Мне главное идею донести.